# Receiving/Parsing XML via email to iOS app

Tags: php, ios, xml, email

I'm a volunteer firefighter looking to build a secondary notification/alert system for our fire and rescue calls. The county sends call data in XML format via email. I'm not looking for specific code help here as much as general functional requirements advice. What I'd like to do is 2 parts:

1) Figure out the best means (or service... though I'd rather set it up myself) to receive these emails and parse the XML with as little delay as possible. Would it be possible to use a gmail account? What sort of service(s) would I need to use? Again, this is secondary to our pagers and radios, so it would need to be very reliable, but doesn't need to be 100%. I'd love to find a way to do this for free or for little costs, as our budget is tight.

2) Figure out the way to get this data into a database. From there I'd like to send push notifications via an iOS app that I'm going to build.

I'm half-decent at PHP and maybe half-half decent in Xcode/Objective C. What services do you think I'll need to go about building this? Thanks so much in advance for any help.

Comment: You should post it at http://elance.com instead of `stackoverflow`

Comment: www.mailgun.com and parse.com might provide some of the platform you need

Comment: Thanks, Paul--those both look great. Much appreciated. Tzar, I'm actually looking to do this myself, not hire a freelancer. Thanks in advance if anyone else has any other advice.